# Google Tag Manager Dynamic Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tag-manager

Is there anyone who knows how to use dynamic function in Gtm. For ex I create a new variable(custom javascript in GTM) called GetName and which is just take 1 parameter.

```
function(name)
 {
   console.log(name);
   return;
 }
```

Now, I want to create a new custom javascript. And that will call the GetName function. But I could not call it. I think I am using wrong syntax.

```
  function()
  {
   {{GetName("test")}} => That not worked
   {{GetName "test"}}  => That not worked

   return;
  }
```

Is there anyone who knows how to call that function in GTM. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

Your first function to return the name:

```
function(){
    return function(name){
        console.log(name);
        return;
    }
}
```

And then to call this:

```
function(){
    var getName = {{GetName}};
    getName("test");
    return;
}
```

Whatever is in the double curly braces is the name of the macro itself, and then anything outside of that can be called like any regular function. If you want to use them in an an event tag for example, then you would need to supply the return value.

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it din t worked well. When I call  getName("test"); , that returns undefined.

Comment: Of course it would return undefined. You are not returning anything in your macros. Do you see the  console returning your input parameter?

Comment: I mean I checkd it in console screen. And it return undefined.

Comment: Modified my answer to fix your first function.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. Yes, I checked it and it worked well. Thanks for your help